# Performance of std::vector::emplace_back vs. assignment for POD struct

Tags: c++, performance, stl

In the below example I see a performance benefit of element assignment (given a vector of the correct size) versus `emplace_back` (given a vector with reserved storage) for a plain old data (POD) struct. Could someone elaborate where this difference comes from?

Thank you very much in advance!

**Notes**

- This question came up within a bigger project and the below is just a MWE
- I did look at the compiler explorer but didn't come up with a good solution
- I do know that the assignment only works because the struct is POD, but I did hope that the compiler would optimize the overhead away, given that C++ is supposed to have zero-overhead abstractions
- Any general recommendations on the code are also welcome and thank you for your input :)

**Code**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <numeric>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::size_t;

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock hrc;
typedef std::chrono::microseconds ms;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;

struct Data {
  int x, y;

  inline Data() noexcept: x(0), y(0) {}

  inline Data(int x, int y) noexcept: x(x), y(y) {}
};

int main() {
  constexpr size_t n = 1000000;
  constexpr size_t reps = 5;

  for (size_t rep = 0; rep < reps; rep++) {
    {
      vector<Data> vec;
      vec.reserve(n);
      auto t1 = hrc::now();
      for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        vec.emplace_back(i, -i);
      auto t2 = hrc::now();
      cout << "Emplace Back: " << duration_cast<ms>(t2 - t1).count() << " ms" << endl;

      // Check
      size_t sum = 0;
      for (auto const &elem : vec)
        sum += elem.x;
      if (sum != ((n * (n - 1)) / 2))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    {
      vector<Data> vec;
      vec.resize(n);
      auto t1 = hrc::now();
      for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        vec[i] = Data(i, i);
      auto t2 = hrc::now();
      cout << "Assign      : " << duration_cast<ms>(t2 - t1).count() << " ms" << endl;

      // Check
      size_t sum = 0;
      for (auto const &elem : vec)
        sum += elem.x;
      if (sum != ((n * (n - 1)) / 2))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string && clang++ -v && clang++ -o main -std=c++17 -O3 main.cpp && ./main
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
Emplace Back: 6162 ms
Assign      : 1000 ms
Emplace Back: 2874 ms
Assign      : 864 ms
Emplace Back: 2149 ms
Assign      : 855 ms
Emplace Back: 2062 ms
Assign      : 934 ms
Emplace Back: 2678 ms
Assign      : 1030 ms
```

Comment: I would say an emplacement as two operations: assign the value and increase the "virtual" size of the vector, where as the assignment is only assigning

Comment: Why did you leave away `vec.reserve(n);` and `vec.resize(n);` in the measurement? It is an important difference between the 2 versions. After that the results are quite similar: https://ideone.com/G1mXty

Comment: @mch if I use his code on the ideone website I got also quite similar timings (without taking reserve and resize into account), so it seems it could be also platform dependent

Comment: Unrelated to your question. If member functions (or constructors)  are defined within the class body there is no need to add `inline` in front of them, because they are implicitly inline.

Comment: I get similar results on my platform.

Comment: So I have similar results, even remove vec.reserve(n) and use push_back instead assignment! emplace_back has lower performance!

Comment: @mch I do know that `vec.reserve(n);` and `vec.resize(n);` are expensive and should be timed. However, in the bigger program that I am actually interested in, the `vec.reserve(n);` and `vec.resize(n);` would be called once, while the `emplace_back` or assignment are called more often. Therefore, the `vec.reserve(n);` and `vec.resize(n);` were not timed.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX, @mch thank you for your comments and for pointing me towards ideone. When I time there without the reserve/resize, I get roughly `1200 ms` vs `800 ms` which is closer but still not the same. Would you have any idea on where this difference comes from?

Comment: @AliRazmkhah if I use `push_back(Data(i, i));` I get similar results on my machine and ideone. However, if I remove the `reserve(n)` the runtime gets notably worse.

Comment: @t.niese Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, two observations:

1. The index access version is missing a negation of the `y` argument:
   compare `vec.emplace_back(i, -i);` vs. `vec[i] = Data(i, i);`
2. The times you're printing are microseconds, or "µs" ("ms" usually means *milliseconds*).
   Given that 1,000,000 iterations take 864 us, one iteration takes 0.8 ns, or just **a couple of CPU cycles**. Comparing that to 2.8 ns, we're talking a difference of *a few cycles* per iteration.

Then some high-level analysis:

The reason the `emplace_back` version takes longer than assignment via index access could be because `emplace_back`, in addition to creating a new element, needs to grow the vector by 1. Even when there's enough reserved space, growing of the vector involves (1) a **check** if there's enough space, and (2) an **update** of the internal vector size field.

Vector index access on the other hand, performs no bounds checking, let alone update any size. It literally does as much as a raw pointer dereference.

The element type, `struct Data` is very simple. Creating, copying or overwriting it should take negligible time.

Finally, we analyze the generated assembly to know for sure what's really going on:

`emplace_back` version:

```
        leaq    8000000(%rax), %r14
        xorl    %ebp, %ebp
        movq    %rbx, %r12
        movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
        jmp     .L14
.L73:
        movl    %ebp, %eax
        movd    %ebp, %xmm0
        addq    $1, %rbp
        addq    $8, %rbx
        negl    %eax
        movd    %eax, %xmm5
        punpckldq       %xmm5, %xmm0
        movq    %xmm0, -8(%rbx)
        cmpq    $1000000, %rbp
        je      .L72
.L14:
        movq    %r14, %r15
        subq    %r12, %r15
        cmpq    %rbx, %r14
        jne     .L73
```

Index access version:

```
        leaq    8000000(%rax), %r13
        . . .
        pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1
        movq    %rax, %r12
        movq    %rbp, %rax
.L27:
        movdqa  .LC3(%rip), %xmm2
        movdqa  %xmm1, %xmm0
        addq    $16, %rax
        paddq   .LC2(%rip), %xmm1
        paddq   %xmm0, %xmm2
        shufps  $136, %xmm2, %xmm0
        movups  %xmm0, -16(%rax)
        cmpq    %rax, %r13
        jne     .L27
```

Conclusion:

1. Overall the compiler did a good job at inlining and eliminating object copying in both versions.
2. The second version is vectorized, writing 2 elements per iteration (possibly due to lack of negation of `y`).
3. The first version is doing more work - we can see the additional counting (`addq $1, %rbp`) and checking (`cmpq $1000000, %rbp`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly the analysis I was looking for :) Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

### What you expect to measure

**emplace_back**
Creates an instance of `Date` by `emplace_back` in the preallocated spaces in `vec`

**assignment**
Creates an instance of **Date** and assigns that to the `Date` object that already exists in `vec`.

### What you likely due measure (due to optimization)

**emplace_back**
Same as above: Creates an instance of `Date` by `emplace_back` in the preallocated spaces in `vec`.
Increases the `size` and checks if new space has to be allocated.

**assignment**
Just assigns - in this case, because `Date` is a really simple object - `i` to the members of `x` and `y` of the already created objected in the `resize` step.

So for the assignment case, you completly miss the time required to create the `Date` objects because you don't include `resize` in the measurment.

### Further explanation

Your `vec.resize(n);` in the *assign* case fills the vector with `n` elements by default constructing them (a placement new is called `n` times). In the loop, an assignment to those created objects happens.

For the first case (`emplace_back`) the `size` (not the capacity) of the vector is increased by one in each iteration and it starts the lifetime of each added object with a *placement new*, while for the second case (*assign*) the `size` does not change and you only assign the `Date` object to the already constructed one.

The compiler could optimize the assignment case to just assign `x` and `y` to the already existing instance in the vector without creating an intermediate `Date` object.

To measure in a meaningful way you need to include `vec.reserve(n)` and `vec.resize(n)`. Currently, you just measure some differences in the optimization process of the compilers.

If you also include `vec.reserve(n)` and `vec.resize(n)` the measuremnts are much closer together.

For such simple classes like the `Date` one there won't be much of a difference between assignment and emplace back, because the construction in the loop of the *assignment* case can often be optimized away.

When you inlcude the `vec.reserve(n)` and `vec.resize(n)` the timing is:

**gcc 8.4**

```
Emplace Back: 11594 ms
Assign      : 11516 ms
Emplace Back: 2001 ms
Assign      : 2691 ms
Emplace Back: 2523 ms
Assign      : 1847 ms
Emplace Back: 1956 ms
Assign      : 1277 ms
Emplace Back: 949 ms
Assign      : 903 ms
```

**clang**

```
Emplace Back: 2115 ms
Assign      : 2640 ms
Emplace Back: 765 ms
Assign      : 766 ms
Emplace Back: 666 ms
Assign      : 540 ms
Emplace Back: 535 ms
Assign      : 515 ms
Emplace Back: 537 ms
Assign      : 543 ms
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As in a comment from me above, the `reserve`/`resize` are not timed on purpose based on the larger program I am actually interested in (not the MWE).

The outline of the operations that happen seem clear, however, what I do not understand is that placement new with given memory and increasing size by one is this much more expensive than assignment. If the optimization is good, placement new should be as expensive as assignment. Is the increment of the size counter this expensive, or am I missing something else?

Comment: @LukasKoestler `emplace_back` not only increases a counter after the assignment, it also checks whether sufficient space is available before the assignment. If you `resize` once and then assign each element, the compiler has a much easier job to optimize the code.

Comment: @LukasKoestler updated the answer I hope it is clearer now.